# How to force reload a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, chatbot, setstate

I'm using an external lib to load a chatbot in my react app, it loads the right way, but according to the page, I need to send new parameters and the chatbot needs to be reloaded, I'm trying to use react state to force reload the chat component, but it's not working.

I'm loading the component like this in App.js:

```
  Chat({
    custom: false,
  });
```

And here is another page where I need to send new parameters, here the route doesn't change, and I'm loading the component like this:

```
  Chat({
    custom: true,
  });
```

And the chat component is like this:

```
export const Chat = ({ custom, status }) => {
  const [chatClient, setChatClient] = useState(new Chat());

  useEffect(() => {
    chatClient
      .withAppKey('APP_KEY')
      .build();

    if (custom) {
       // According to the documentation, I can remove the chat instance, that's what I'm trying to do here
      chatClient.destroy();

      setChatClient(new Chat());

      chatClient
        .withAppKey('APP_KEY')
        .extraParams(status)
        .build();
    }

    return () => {
      chatClient.destroy();
    };
  }, []);
};
```

The first chat is loaded correctly, the second one, when I call the chat again with new parameters, it doesn't load. What could I be doing wrong?

I really appreciate if anyone can help me!

Comment: Is `blipChat` meant to be a hook or a component ? Anyways it's improperly named as there's already a `BlipChat`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `custom and status` as dependencies if they constantly change. , useEffect will detect the change and run again.

```
    ...
    }, [custom, status]);
```

Comment: I did and still the same, the second chat does not load =(

Answer (score 0):

try to create local variable inside function and then apply it to state

```
  const newBlipChat = new BlipChat();
  setBlipClient(newBlipChat);

  newBlipChat
    .withAppKey('APP_KEY')
    .withButton({ color: 'black' })
    .withCustomCommonUrl('myCustomUrl')
    .extraParams(status)
    .build();
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike It seems that there was an advance here, but I have a problem to delete the previous instance with the error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'destroy')

and I am doing exactly what is in the documentation

Comment: check before delete `blipClient?.destroy();`